# Install Autoconf, Automake trying to install pcre

Tags: install, binary

I don't asking by homebrew or port only source code /binary

I was trying to install **pcre**...

```
$ cd /Volumes/ADATAHD/macOS/Source_Codes/pcre-8.39
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Custom/pcre --enable-unicode-properties --enable-pcre16 --enable-pcre32

pcre-8.39 configuration summary:

    Install prefix .................. : /usr/local/Custom/pcre
    C preprocessor .................. : gcc -E
    C compiler ...................... : gcc
    C++ preprocessor ................ : g++ -E
    C++ compiler .................... : g++
    Linker .......................... : /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld
    C preprocessor flags ............ : 
    C compiler flags ................ : -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden
    C++ compiler flags .............. : -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
    Linker flags .................... : 
    Extra libraries ................. : 

    Build 8 bit pcre library ........ : yes
    Build 16 bit pcre library ....... : yes
    Build 32 bit pcre library ....... : yes
    Build C++ library ............... : yes
    Enable JIT compiling support .... : no
    Enable UTF-8/16/32 support ...... : yes
    Unicode properties .............. : yes
    Newline char/sequence ........... : lf
    \R matches only ANYCRLF ......... : no
    EBCDIC coding ................... : no
    EBCDIC code for NL .............. : n/a
    Rebuild char tables ............. : no
    Use stack recursion ............. : yes
    POSIX mem threshold ............. : 10
    Internal link size .............. : 2
    Nested parentheses limit ........ : 250
    Match limit ..................... : 10000000
    Match limit recursion ........... : MATCH_LIMIT
    Build shared libs ............... : yes
    Build static libs ............... : yes
    Use JIT in pcregrep ............. : no
    Buffer size for pcregrep ........ : 20480
    Link pcregrep with libz ......... : no
    Link pcregrep with libbz2 ....... : no
    Link pcretest with libedit ...... : no
    Link pcretest with libreadline .. : no
    Valgrind support ................ : no
    Code coverage ................... : no
```

Now... **make**

```
$ make
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /Volumes/ADATAHD/macOS/Source_Codes/pcre-8.39/missing aclocal-1.15 -I m4
/Volumes/ADATAHD/macOS/Source_Codes/pcre-8.39/missing: line 81: aclocal-1.15: command not found
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.15' is missing on your system.
        You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
        'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
        The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
        <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
        It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
        <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
        <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
        <http://www.perl.org/>
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
$
```

Let's go to install **autoconf**

```
$ tar zxvf /Volumes/ADATAHD/Downloads/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz -C /Volumes/ADATAHD/macOS/Source_Codes/
$ cd /Volumes/ADATAHD/macOS/Source_Codes/autoconf-2.69
```

Running

```
$ sudo ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

I have this error message:

```
standards.texi:3229: Unknown command `guilsinglleft'.
standards.texi:3229: Misplaced {.
standards.texi:3229: Misplaced }.
standards.texi:3229: Unknown command `guilsinglright'.
standards.texi:3229: Misplaced {.
standards.texi:3229: Misplaced }.
makeinfo: Removing output file `standards.info' due to errors; use --force to preserve.
make[2]: *** [standards.info] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
$
```

**How solve this error?**
Another Question, **Why libz is not detected?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem arises because you are using an external hard drive.
Then the configuration script can't change the date and time of certain files like:

```
acinclude.m4
configure.ac
```

On the other hand you can update the date and time of the required files using `touch ...` yourself.

Related: [How to overcome “'aclocal-1.15' is missing on your system” warning when compiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278928/how-to-overcome-aclocal-1-15-is-missing-on-your-system-warning-when-compilin)

Comment: The script uses exactly the same code to chnage the data and time of files as touch does. I'll even bet the script uses touch

Comment: Works fine for me, moving from `/Volumes/ADATAHD/macOS/Source_Codes/pcre-8.39` to `/Users/myuser/Documents/pcre-8.39`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the work-around published here to solve the problem:

https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb/issues/77

The work-around consists of disabling the generation of the info pages (manual).

It seems this error is there because you have an older, incompatible version of TeX. Perhaps you're using an old version of OS X.